# HashCode calculation from double

Tags: java, double, overriding, long-integer, hashcode

In [Effective Java](https://books.google.lt/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=%28longBits%20%5E%20%28longBits%20%3E%3E%3E%2032%29%29;&source=bl&ots=yZEkLlv5P4&sig=WwduZISkIGl6QRwGnzijmz5WS8g&hl=lt&sa=X&ei=Fo71VIuIOoPtUuXagsgG&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=(longBits%20%5E%20(longBits%20%3E%3E%3E%2032))%3B&f=false) there is an example of Complex class. That class has overridden hashCode which uses hashDouble method I have a question about.

```
private int hashDouble(double val) 
{
    long longBits = Double.doubleToLongBits(re);
    return (int) (longBits ^ (longBits >>> 32));
}
```

For what purpose it does `(int) (longBits ^ (longBits >>> 32))`?

Comment: Uh well, to return a hash code... What is your question exactly?

Comment: What is the intent behind `longBits ^ (longBits >>> 32)` ? Why not for example just do only `longBits >>> 32` .

Comment: Well according to the java doc the `>>>` shifts to the right and fills with zeros. So the first 32 bits would be zero after that operation.

Comment: Because the hash wouldn't be as good?

Comment: `(int) longbits` does only take the lesser 32 bit into account `(longBits >>> 32)` only the higher. `longBits ^ (longBits >>> 32)` uses all 64 bits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double value is 64 bits wide but the int returned by hash method has only 32 bit.
In order to achieve a better distribution of hash values (compared to simply striping the upper 32 bits).

The code uses [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) to incorporate the upper 32 bits (containing sign, exponent and some bits of the mantissa) aligned by right-shifting of the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) value in the calculation.

[image]

<sup>Image source Wikipedia</sup>